# Stopping an endless loop through a char array being used in a maze - Java

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

OK, so I have a maze program I have created for class. When I use a manually created char array as my map, everything works as it should, the rat runs around looking for the exit and the program stops when it finds it. I am now trying to generate a random char array map to run through my maze program, but when I do, it just endlessly loops through the steps it takes to try and find the end, even though I can see in the steps that it has at least reached where the exit should be.

I have noticed that the first time it hits where the exit should be, the address in memory is printed out, and then it continues on looping. It looks like this in the console:

"
I Hit A Wall

I'm going back from point (11, 9) to point (10, 9)

[[C@276af2

I'm going back from point (10, 10) to point (10, 9)

I Am Repeating My Steps
"

This is what I am using to generate the char array:

```
public void randMazeFill(int row, int col){
     Random r = new Random(row-1);
    char[][] map = new char[row][col];
    for(int i = 0; i < row; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < col; j++){
            if(i == 0 && j > 0 || i > 0 && j ==0 || i == 0 && j == 0 || i == row-1 || j == col-1 
                    ||i == r.nextInt(row-2) || j == r.nextInt(col-2) || i == r.nextInt(row-2) && j == r.nextInt(col-2) ){
                map[i][j] = '1';
            }else if(i == 1 && j == 1){
                map[i][j] = 'B';
            }else if(i == row - 2 && j == col - 2){
                map[i][j] = 'E';
            }
            else 
            map[i][j] = '0';
        }
    }
    for(int a = 0; a < map.length; a++)
        System.arraycopy(map[a], 0, mazeGrid[a], 0, map[a].length);
}
```

It creates an array that has the outer borders surrounded as 1's, some randon 1's as walls inside the array, a "B" for the beginning, and an "E" for the end. I have a recursive function that goes through and searches through the array, looking for the "E". Since it's a current assignment, I can't post all of the code for that, but I can show some.

Here's how it starts out:

```
public void runThrough(int x, int y){
    if(myMaze[x][y] == 'E'){
        count++;
        myMaze[x][y] = footSteps;
        System.out.println(myMaze);
        return;
    }
```

Here's a basic idea of the rest of the method:

```
if(x < 0 || x > size - 1 || y < 0 || y > size - 1){
        return;
    }

    if(mazeGrid[x][y] == '1'){
        System.out.println("I Hit A Wall");
        return;
    }

    if(mazeGrid[x][y] == footSteps){
        System.out.println("I Am Repeating My Steps");
        return;
    }

    //Recursive Case
    if(mazeGrid[x][y] == 'B'){
        do something
    }else
    mazeGrid[x][y] = footSteps;

    runThrough(x + 1, y); // printout

    runThrough(x, y + 1); // printout

    runThrough(x - 1, y); // printout

    runThrough(x, y - 1); // printout

    mazeGrid[x][y] = 'b'+'t'; //backtracking
```

This looks to see if it has hit the "E" on the grid. If it does, the recursion stops and the map is printed out, showing where the mouse walked. If it doesn't hit the "E" then I have it check each available spot next to its location to see if it can move there, in which case it does, and then rechecks to see if it's found the "E".

I'm thinking I am doing something wrong in my map generation that is causing the memory address where the "E" is stored to pop up in the original check, thus making the program continue to run. Anybody have an idea on how I can fix this, or a suggestion for a better way of doing this?

Oh, and just in case it's needed, here's a copy of one of the hand made maps that don't seem to have this problem:

```
public static char[][] ratMap1 = new char[][]{ 
    {'1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'},
    {'1', 'B', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', 'E', '0', '1'},
    {'1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1'},
    {'1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1'},
    {'1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1'},
    {'1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1'},
    {'1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1'},
    {'1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1'},
    {'1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1'},
    {'1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'}};
```

Comment: Hi.  Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive. You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen. As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem. (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).)

Comment: Paste the piece of code where you use the runThrough method.

Comment: In runThrough(): What is footSteps and where do you get count from?

Comment: footsteps is a separate char in the data section used to create a mark for where the mouse has been in the grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is, your method does not break any while(true) loop. When you find your maze, you print the message about finding exit and return FROM THE runThrough method, not from the main loop. To achieve what you want, decalare Boolean flag (say mazeSolvedFlag) in your class and try something like:

```
if(myMaze[x][y] == 'E'){
    count++;
    myMaze[x][y] = footSteps;
    System.out.println(myMaze);
    mazeSolvedFlag = true;
}
```

and run your code in

```
while(!mazeSolvedFlag){
   //your code
}
```

loop.

The specific map provided by you may work, because after reaching exit your rat hits the wall from three sides and repeat his own steps from the last remaining side, so it ends because of this conditions:

```
 if(mazeGrid[x][y] == '1'){
    System.out.println("I Hit A Wall");
    return;
}

if(mazeGrid[x][y] == footSteps){
    System.out.println("I Am Repeating My Steps");
    return;
}
```

Comment: Well that worked, so thanks for that. I'm still wondering why it's only doing this with the random generated map and not the hand made ones.

Comment: I think it might have hit the wall from all sides after reaching E and escaped because of hitting the wall, so it's not an issue of random generation, but of this single, specific map picked by you. try to generate manually other maps and see results.

Comment: Ha! And now, with the boolean check, the hand generated maps are doing the endless loop. Now I'm really confused.

Comment: Never mind, it was looping because I had changed one of my maps and it didn't have any access to the exit. Thanks again!